# WebView is not loading HTML5 video in android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

```
    WebView wvVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvVideo);
    String ytVideo= "<html><body><iframe width='350' height='160' src='www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqNGzYsPN6M' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
    wvVideo.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wvVideo.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wvVideo.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wvVideo.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wvVideo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvVideo.loadData(ytVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It just display thumbnail and when i click on that, its not playing. just display black screen. my API Target is 15 and i set all the required permissions for that but still not working.

Comment: anything shown in LogCat ?

Comment: no but as i said it just display black screen..

Comment: @Segi found any solution for this??

Comment: @Segi Have you found any solution for this?. Please share how you achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings seems fine.
As for me the following settings did the job on my project which play HTML5 videos. Try them

```
   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // I think you will need this one
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);// no need I think

    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);

   webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // dont forget this one
```

Add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to your manifest file.

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Comment: Did you add this line webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); ? @Segi

Comment: The only other difference I have noticed is I am using webview.loadUrl(); to set the url,  and you are using webview.loadData(). Not sure if it has something to do with the problem, but mine is working.

Comment: and I assuming you are testing on device not emulator

Comment: Make sure you add an import: ’import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;’