# Get stream from IP Webcam

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I was trying to get the stream from IP Webcam app on Android in browser mode for some time but was unsuccessful.
I tried with webview loading a html page hosted on my laptop not working in my app but works in chrome for android ...Here is my code :

**Camera.html**

```
 <img id="browser_video" class="video-image" alt="video" src="http://192.168.1.101:8080/video">
```

**MainActivity**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity{


        WebView wv;
        String URL = "http://192.168.1.187:8080/camera.html";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvImage);  
            wv.loadUrl(URL);
         }
   }
```

And **activity_main** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What to try next?

This is how it looks on chrome and on my app

http://i1258.photobucket.com/albums/ii532/csanonymus/Screenshot_2014-07-01-17-57-28_zps22e1e220.png

http://i1258.photobucket.com/albums/ii532/csanonymus/Screenshot_2014-07-01-17-57-07_zpsad9244d3.png

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have:

```
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Does it just show a blank screen?

EDIT: In AndroidManifest.xml for activity tag add android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

My own IP Camera code:

Here is the IP Camera controller

```
public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

String url = "http://192.168.1.187:8080/camera.html";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mini_bot_controller);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String myIP = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
    webview.loadUrl(url);


}


}
```

Then the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MiniBotController.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Hope this helped.

Note: It's also worth mentioning that this program starts in a fragment where you input the IP Address and hit 'Play' and it runs the Webview.

Hopefully last EDIT: I modified the code to just be drag and drop, you need two files. One named WebViewActivity and one named MainActivity. The main activity starts the intent for the second activity which will handle everything. This is a WORKING example as I have to use this one on occasion.

Comment: Yes a white screen..I added a button in the camera.html and it only shows the button...I followed your answer but still the same

Comment: Also set up your webviewclient:
`wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());` 

Also see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182860/webview-is-not-loading-html5-video-in-android

Comment: Still empty..It's getting really frustrating!!

Comment: I don't know how to use all this.

Comment: @marcelinho I made this a drag and drop program. Please check it out. I hope to have answered your question because I've made a lot of noob mistakes.

Comment: Thank you..It's clearer now..But where do you get MyWebViewClient()?

Comment: @marcelinho Oh sorry. I forgot to delete that part. That MyWebViewClient was a subclass class to handle the URL that was given. For instance I used that class to automatically log me into my IP Camera's handle using `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`. You could also look up the function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html if you need to know more. 

Did you get your code working?

Comment: I did but the hard way...I made a handler with a delayed runnable to take a picture from the ip app every 50 ms...But I don't really like it this way because it's so laggy....